# Installation Problem: Cannot find module Yarn

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg

Today I decided to install yarn and I tried to install it with `npm i -g` and `brew install`, however whenever I run `yarn -v` this error appears:

```sh
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/franciscomendes/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

When I run the `which yarn` command this is the path that appears (when I install with HomeBrew):

```sh
/usr/local/bin/yarn
```

When I look for .yarn using `which .yarn` this appears in the terminal:

```sh
.yarn not found
```

If I install globally with npm and then list my global dependencies, note that I have version 1.22.11, however the error persists.

```sh
/Users/franciscomendes/.npm-global/lib
├── autocannon@7.0.5
├── clinic@8.0.1
├── expo-cli@4.5.2
├── npm-check-updates@11.4.1
├── npm@
├── serve@12.0.0
└── yarn@1.22.11
```

And when I run the `which yarn` command, this is the path that appears:

```sh
/Users/franciscomendes/.npm-global/bin/yarn
```

Do you have a solution for this problem?

P.S.:By the way, node and npm work normally (as well as others).

Comment: Are you trying to install yarn 3 or the more used version 1?

Comment: I would like to use version 1.

Comment: Yarn called its version 3 `berry` which is why I think you may be installing 3 here. https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/yarn says that version 1 is the latest so running `brew install yarn` should install 1. What command did you use to install yarn? (Also make sure you run `brew update` before you run the install)

Comment: I noticed that. But I don't understand why the yarn command simply doesn't work. If I install globally with npm, the yarn version is 1.22.11. However, I have the exact same problem.

Comment: `which` command only works for files in `PATH` (executables, usually)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Check if you have an **.yarnrc** file in your repo, if you have it, just delete it and try to run `yarn` and must work

Answer (score 0):

Do `which yarn` and if the path includes a `.yarn`, go to that path, delete everything with .yarn and .yarnrc.yml.

Answer (score -1):

```
ll -a ~
rm -fdr .yarnrc.yml
curl -o ~/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs \ https://repo.yarnpkg.com/1.22.19/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js`
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Actually, the call to `https://repo.yarnpkg.com/1.22.19/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js` retrieves a 404 Not found error message. So you will end up having a `yarn-1.22.19.cjs` file with content "404 Not Found", as that curl is inserting the response of the request to that url into the cjs file. 
Btw, the path of your `cjs` file might be different.